# Most efficient way to calculate hamming distance in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hamming-distance

In ruby, what is the most efficient way to calculate the bit difference between two unsigned integers (e.g. the hamming distance)?

Eg, I have integer a = 2323409845 and b = 1782647144.

Their binary representations are:

```
a = 10001010011111000110101110110101
b = 01101010010000010000100101101000
```

The bit difference between the a & b is 17..

I can do a logical XOR on them, but that will give me a different integer != 17, I would then have to iterate through the binary representation of the result and tally the # of 1s.

What is the most efficient way to calculate the bit difference?

Now, does the answer change for calculating the bit difference of sequences of many ints? E.g. given 2 sequences of unsigned integers:

```
x = {2323409845,641760420,509499086....}
y = {uint,uint,uint...}
```

What is the most efficient way to calculate the bit difference between the two sequences?

Would you iterate through the sequence, or is there a faster way to calculate the difference across the entire sequence at once?

Comment: Thanks! I just did that and it seems to be 3X faster than the method below (using Ruby's optimized string functions)

Comment: I'm very late to this party, but you might want to take [this popcount benchmark](http://dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/popcnt.cpp) for a spin. `__builtin_popcount` is among the slowest methods if you don't [use a compile flag](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2011/11/02/faster_popcount_update.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make use of the optimized String functions in Ruby to do the bit counting, instead of pure arithmetic. It turns out to be about 6 times faster with some quick benchmarking.

```
def h2(a, b)
  (a^b).to_s(2).count("1")
end
```

h1 is the normal way to calculate, while h2 converts the xor into a string, and counts the number of "1"s

Benchmark:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180:001:0>> def h1(a, b)
ruby-1.9.2-p180:002:1*> ret = 0
ruby-1.9.2-p180:003:1*> xor = a ^ b
ruby-1.9.2-p180:004:1*> until xor == 0
ruby-1.9.2-p180:005:2*> ret += 1
ruby-1.9.2-p180:006:2*> xor &= xor - 1
ruby-1.9.2-p180:007:2*> end
ruby-1.9.2-p180:008:1*> ret
ruby-1.9.2-p180:009:1*> end
# => nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180:010:0>> def h2(a, b)
ruby-1.9.2-p180:011:1*> (a^b).to_s(2).count("1")
ruby-1.9.2-p180:012:1*> end
# => nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180:013:0>> h1(2323409845, 1782647144)
# => 17
ruby-1.9.2-p180:014:0>> h2(2323409845, 1782647144)
# => 17
ruby-1.9.2-p180:015:0>> quickbench(10**5) { h1(2323409845, 1782647144) }
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   2.060000   0.000000   2.060000 (  1.944690)
--------------------------- total: 2.060000sec

       user     system      total        real
   1.990000   0.000000   1.990000 (  1.958056)
# => nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180:016:0>> quickbench(10**5) { h2(2323409845, 1782647144) }
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.333673)
--------------------------- total: 0.340000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.326854)
# => nil
ruby-1.9.2-p180:017:0>>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I found this was a lot faster as well. Doing roughly 21K comparisons using the built in string function as you suggested took about 3 seconds, where as the traditional way took twice as long

Answer (score 6):

Per the suggestion of mu is too short, I wrote a simple C extension to use __builtin_popcount , and using benchmark verified that it is at least 3X faster than ruby's optimized string functions..

I looked at the following two tutorials:

- [Extending Ruby With C](http://rubysource.com/extending-ruby-with-c/)
- [Ruby Extension in C in 5 min](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html)

In my program:

```
require './FastPopcount/fastpopcount.so'
include FastPopcount

def hamming(a,b)
  popcount(a^b)
end
```

Then in the dir containing my program, I create a folder "PopCount" with the following files.

extconf.rb:

```
# Loads mkmf which is used to make makefiles for Ruby extensions
require 'mkmf'

# Give it a name
extension_name = 'fastpopcount'

# The destination
dir_config(extension_name)

# Do the work
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

popcount.c:

```
// Include the Ruby headers and goodies
#include "ruby.h"

// Defining a space for information and references about the module to be stored internally
VALUE FastPopcount = Qnil;

// Prototype for the initialization method - Ruby calls this, not you
void Init_fastpopcount();

// Prototype for our method 'popcount' - methods are prefixed by 'method_' here
VALUE method_popcount(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self);

// The initialization method for this module
void Init_fastpopcount() {
    FastPopcount = rb_define_module("FastPopcount");
    rb_define_method(FastPopcount, "popcount", method_popcount, 1); 
}

// Our 'popcount' method.. it uses the builtin popcount
VALUE method_popcount(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
    return INT2NUM(__builtin_popcount(NUM2UINT(argv)));
}
```

Then in the popcount directory run:

ruby extconf.rb
make

Then run the program, and there you have it....fastest way to do hamming distance in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm of Wegner:

```
def hamm_dist(a, b)
  dist = 0
  val = a ^ b

  while not val.zero?
    dist += 1
    val &= val - 1
  end
  dist
end

p hamm_dist(2323409845, 1782647144) # => 17
```

Answer (score 1):

If one intends to follow c-based path, it is a good idea to add the compiler flag `-msse4.2` to your makefile. This allows the compiler to generate hardware based `popcnt` instructions instead of using a table to generate the popcount. On my system this was approximately 2.5x faster.