# Is there any support for extending Ruby using C on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, heroku

I am trying to quickly calculate the hamming distance between two 64 bit integers in Ruby. I quickly discovered that even with Ruby's optimized string functions etc. it wouldn't be enough, so I turned to C extensions. For comparison, Pure Ruby benchmarked at about 350,000 comparisons per second and C extensions benchmarked at around 4,000,000.

I used the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397116/4196243) and compiled it on my computer where it worked fine. The problem I have is using it on Heroku. I tried `ruby extconf.rb make` to create the makefile, which worked, and then `make` to compile it which failed with `make: gcc: Command not found`. It doesn't matter to me if I do this on deploy or not, but I don't know how to run code automatically at deploy. This has vexed me - if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to create a Gem containing the C extension, which would then be compiled when it is installed during deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Heroku Buildpacks to solve this https://blog.heroku.com/buildpacks

I did some work with the linguist gem which required C extensions to work and solved it by using the correct buildpack.

You can either use a prebuilt buildpack or build your own

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16764489)

Comment: I edited the comment to include more instructions in case the link changes